# Getting the current page number vertical UIScrollView ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a vertical scrollview in IOS. I am unable to get the page number for it. I could get the page number for horizontal scroll but not for a vertical scroll.

How can I get it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your post to include what have you tried so far and what results / errors you encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply get the contentOffset y of your scrollView and then divide it with the height of the frame. Something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView { 
    int pageNo = round(YOUR_SCROLL_VIEW.contentOffset.y / YOUR_SCROLL_VIEW.frame.size.height); 
    NSLog(@"Page number is %i", pageNo); 

}
```

I have added this in `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method but it's upto you to decide where to add it as per requirements. This logic works for me.

Comment: What if i have multiple vertical scrollviews in same name?

Comment: Why/How would you have multiple UI objects in a same name?

Comment: I have added multiple vertical scroll view on a horizontal scrollview using forloop.